# How to link a source to project in Intellij that tomcat will be able to use the class files? (like in eclipse)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I had 3 different project in elicpse,  Two of them is the web app, and the order one is a common project.

I setup in eclipse the Tomcat server (running it from eclipse) in order that tomcat will detect the classes inside the comon project i had to add it to the build path to solve the compile time issue and add the jar / add the source as link in order that tomcat will detect the class files.

So, i moved everything to Intellij, was looking to a way to add the source as link, to be able to run tomcat from Intellij, is there any way to do it there? (insted of adding the jar of the common project)

Comment: build common project to **jar** file, then add this jar file to library of per other project. Or use only one IDE, don't use many of them.

Comment: @ĐỗNhưVý currently I'm using only Intellij. i dont want to build the jar everytime i'm changing the class now, i need something that will work now fast as i can, later on i will use the jar (when the common project will be more stable and static)

Comment: All of 3 projects are must be Maven projects. Commons project will have version number is x.x.x-SNAPSHOT (must have key word `SNAPSHOT`). 2 other project has dependency is `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT`. `SNAPSHOT` is very special, it make `x.x.x-SNAPSHOT` always is new per Maven goal action.

Comment: @ĐỗNhưVý so i guess there is not away to add another souce as linke like eclispe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an artefact in IntelliJ. You can do it from the menu `File -> Project Structure...`. I would create Web Application: Exploded.

[image]

You can link all your sources, dependencies and web content there. I assume that you have all 3 parts in a single IntelliJ project as modules.

Then you can create a runner for starting tomcat server with your application in `Run -> Edit Configurations...`

[image]

Then you will just pickup the artefact in deployment section. You will use the `+` button. You should get as an option your artefact. You can specify deployment context. By default it is root (`/`).

[image]

The last thing which might be needed is where do you have your Tomcat server installed. IntelliJ doesn't have tomcat bundled in it's installation. You can setup your Tomcat home on the `Server` tab.